# Calling multiple numbers together in android

Tags: java, android, webrtc

I want to call multiple numbers together programmatically. Like on one button click I want to call 3 contact numbers together. Like I should start a conference call with already all 3 calls in merged state. What is the right approach to do this?

Comment: Can you even start a conference call all at once using your phone dialer?!

Comment: You have put `webRTC` tag in question . Is your question about WebRTC call of Telecom call ?

Comment: There are sure 3 steps to start a conference call. 1. You call one number, 2. You call 2nd number, 3. You click on merge. I just want to know if there is anything in android to make a conference call just by one click. Thanks!

Comment: I read that WebRTC allows audio and video communication by allowing peer-to-peer communication. While researching on this topic, I came across WebRTC a lot. So I thought this tag is relevant.

Comment: Hi Rashmi, have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but you may take a look at the [Conference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Conference) API, it seems that you can add multiple connections